# Value and decimal in html number input

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a number input which you accept only, 7 digits before the decimal point and 2 digits after the decimal points.

I tried out min, max and giving step as attribute but it is not efficient. any work around with javascript?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: try using regular expressions

Comment: can someone get me the regular expression for this validation?